# See original type definition in watch-window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

My application contains some `CMap` objects, filled with a `CString` and a `LPCTSTR` string, and some internal objects, like here:

```
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, Internal_ObjectDBInfo*> m_mapInternal_ObjectDBInfo;
```

The `CString` and `LPCTSTR` strings are equal to some other types, as mentioned in some `typedef` structures:

```
typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC_DLL< TCHAR > > CString; // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\afxstr.h
typedef LPCWSTR PCTSTR, LPCTSTR;                                  // C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h
typedef _Null_terminated_ CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;          // ...
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;                                            // ...
```

In my watch-window, those `typedef` structures are followed to the end, which shows a heavy `Type` column in the watch-window, as you can see here:

```
Name                             Value  Type
===========================+===========+==========================================================================================================================
m_mapInternal_ObjectDBInfo | { size=0 }| CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,Internal_ObjectDBInfo *>
```

I'd like Visual Studio not to follow the entire `typedef` structures, in order to have a clearer `Type` column in the watch-window, something like this:

```
Name                             Value  Type
===========================+===========+===============================================
m_mapInternal_ObjectDBInfo | { size=0 }| CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, Internal_ObjectDBInfo*>
```

Is this possible? I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, version 15.9.13.

As this seems not to be possible currently, [a suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/620703/see-original-type-definition-in-watch-window.html) has been raised for the Visual Studio development community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the display format in `Type` column.

I'm afraid the answer is negative, for now there is no option or feature in VS support this behavior.

There are some topics in Microsoft Documents about how to create custom views of objects in debugger, but it seems they only support changing the display Value or Name, but not Type format.

You can check: [Create custom views of native C++ objects in the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019) and [Create custom views of objects for managed C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-dot-managed-objects?view=vs-2019). But they're not useful to meet your needs.

And if you do want something more clear in Watch window, I suggest you `go Help menu`=>`Seed feedback`=>`Provide a suggestion` to post it. Let the team know your idea and share the link here after that, members interested in it will vote for you. But as I mentioned above, for now it's not possible, so there might be a long way to go before this new feature comes.

Comment: I've followed it and you can consider adding this link to your question, more members could easily see it :)